# Table keys for SSAS project?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012, ssas, sql-server-data-tools

I'm creating a very basic cube with the data that I have. This is my scenario; please let me know if I'm approaching this the wrong way.

In our case, there's data in fact table `FactSalesDaily` that my dim table `DimEmp` doesn't have, and I want to know what that data is.

I have three tables: `FactSalesDaily`, `DimDate`, `DimEmp`

```
[FactSalesDaily]
EmpKey    DateKey       SalesAmount
194       20170125      45.30
195       20170125      21.00

[DimDate]
DateKey   FullDate
20170125  01-25-2017

[DimEmp]
EmpKey     FullName
194        Joe Smith
```

As you can see, my fact table has `EmpKey` *195* that's not part of `DimEmp`. My understanding is that in the `Data Source View Wizard`, when I click on *Add Related Tables*, the wizard will display the related tables based on the foreign keys for fact table `FactSalesDaily`.

In my particular case, I would like to see the total sales for employee *195*. But I can't add a foreign key of `FactSalesDaily` to `DimEmp` because *195* doesn't exist.

As a result, `Data Source View Wizard` will not select `DimEmp` because there's not relationship between the two tables.

How am I supposed to deal with this issue? I can add a bogus row in `DimEmp` for all the employees that don't exist, but then I'd have to alter `FactSalesDaily` by replacing `195` with this bogus row.

Thanks.

Comment: You could make views that deal with the missing data, both replacing things that don't link up in the fact view with an 'unknown' employee key', and adding an unknown row in the view for dimemployee. Then you can use these views in the DSV rather than your actual tables.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So I don't need foreign keys to create these relationships in the DSV?

Comment: Not actual foreign keys in the db - you just say which columns relate to which other columns. For the unknown rows they could both be 0

Comment: No foreign keys then. But I would only add the unknown row to dimemployee? Or do I need to alter my factsales so that the unknown employee is also 0?

Comment: In other words, I would only alter the view in dimemployee? No need to alter the data in the fact table?

Comment: You'd make vwDimEmployee that UNIONs the contents of DimEmployee with one extra row representing unknown with zero as its key, and vwFactSales that takes the contents of FactSales and replaces the employeekey with zero if it's one you can't find in dimemployee (left outer Join to find out)

Comment: Then I would lose employee 195. I would know that there are sales from unknown employees, but I would not know that 195 is one of them. I just know that everything's under "0"

Comment: You'd know 195 was one of them if you left outer joined to dim employee in your vwFactSales

Comment: Yes, in tsql, but not in the cube. If I connect Excel to the cube, I won't see 195 anywhere. I will just know that all unknown sales are under "0".

Comment: What is your desired outcome?   "How...to deal with this issue" is more of a business-rules question than a programming question.  If it were me, I'd be looking for a way to prevent 195 from getting into my fact table in the first place.   Where did a non-existent employee ID come from?   What real-world fact does 195 represent?   Is there an actual employee 195 who isn't in your employee table?   How did that happen?

Comment: Good point! You could add 195 as a row into your vwDimEmployee. Or have a second field in vwFactSales for your employeekey, leave it in so people can see it as a detail. Lots of ways to solve it, depending on the requirements.